# How can we utilize the custom @Qualifier methods?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have multiple questions related to how annotation methods are implemented/utilized.

How can we utilize methods of a qualifier? Let's say I have a custom `@Qualifier` ie. `@Store` which represents an AppStore, and has 2 methods. How can I use the values passed to `DeviceType deviceType()`?

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Store {

    String value();

    DeviceType deviceType() default DeviceType.Phone;

    public enum DeviceType{
        Phone, Tablet;
    }
```

}

How does `@Qualifier` internally uses the `String value()` for matching the name?
Is the same being overridden by the `String value()` when creating a custom `@Qualifier`?

--- **UPDATED INFO BELOW** ---

I have a service that contains a field of type AppStore, which has an @Autowired and @Store annotation. How can i access the deviceType passes in the annotation after getting a bean of iPadAppStoreService?

```
@Service
public class iPadAppStoreService {

....

    @Autowired(required=false)
    @Store(value = "appleAppStore",
    deviceType = DeviceType.Tablet)
    private AppStore applicationStore;

....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access the deviceType"? Access from where? --- I assume that `AppStore` is an interface, and that you have multiple implementation classes, each annotated with `@Store` too. Would those annotations have element `deviceType`, and what would that signify?

Comment: So this example is just for understanding the concept. deviceType signifies if it's a tablet or a phone. As there might be different instances of app store depending on these device types. So, we may have a different instance of an iPadAppStore and an iPhoneAppStore.

Comment: That is what the `value` element of `@Qualifier` is for, to choose the `AppStore` implementation that deals with `iPad` vs `iPhone`. If you only have an `apple` implementation, then where in the code does the `deviceType` get used? To repeat my question: Access `deviceType` *from where*?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we utilize methods of a qualifier?

You call them.

---

> Let's say I have a custom `@Qualifier` ie. `@Store` which represents an AppStore, and has 2 methods. How can I use the values passed to `DeviceType deviceType()`?

```java
Store storeAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Store.class);
DeviceType deviceType = storeAnnotation.deviceType();
```

where `clazz` is a class that has been annotated with `@Store`.

---

> How does `@Qualifier` internally uses the `String value()` for matching the name?

If an `@Autowired` field/method/parameter finds multiple candidates by type and there is also a `@Qualifier` annotation (or a derived annotation like `@Store`), it will look for a candidate type that has been annotated with `@Qualifier` with a matching `value` element.

---

> Is the same being overridden by the `String value()` when creating a custom `@Qualifier`?

Yes, the `@Store` annotation will be treated the same way as the `@Qualifier` annotation, i.e. its element values will be used the same way. Any extra element values are ignored by Spring, and will only be used by code you add.

Comment: I have updated some more information. I want to retrieve the information set as deviceType when i get the bean iPadAppStoreService.

Comment: What i meant by asking "How does Qualifier internally uses the String value() for matching the name?" is where is the implementation for that method, as i might have to add a new method in my custom Qualifier, which would contain some logic.